How i can know the number of requests our Power Apps is consuming per day for each user
We have a solution that contain one Power Apps connected to SharePoint lists, and around 20 power automate flows. Now i need to know how many requests the Power Apps is consuming for each user per 24 hours. i thought i can get this info from the "Power Platform Admin" >> "Resource" >> "Capacity" , as per this documentation @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations#view-detailed-power-platform-request-usage-information-in-the-power-platform-admin-center-preview .
But when i generated the report,it will show the number of requests for Power Automate & Data Verse only, but will not show the info for Power Apps, where this will be zero for all users, as follow:-

So why the above capacity report is not counting the requests for the Power Apps? is it a bug in the report ? if so, then what other approaches we can follow to get this info?
Second question, i want to know this for future planning after the Power Automate transition period ends, where each user with seeded Power Platform license will have a limit of 8K requests per day, which most of our users have..Now let say we realize that most users consume more than 8k requests per day through using the Power Apps. then can we license the Power App itself instead of licensing the users who are using it? so for example, we can allow our Power Apps to do for example 1 Million requests per day for all users? is this an available license approach? if so, then  how much -approximately- this will cost us?
Thanks
